# Error con multiplicación de una matriz y un escalar en Python

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy tratando de hacer un método que retorne el resultado de multiplicar una constante por una matriz, este es el código que tengo:

```
from sympy import *
#from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from py_expression_eval import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#1,2 es una fila
#3,4 otra fila
#M = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
def matrizPorEscalar(matriz1, escalar):
    matriz1 = np.matrix(matriz1)
    return matriz1 * escalar
M1 = input("Ingrese la matriz de la forma [1, 2] (esto es una fila) (USAMOS ; PARA SEPARAR DE LA SIGUIENTE FILA), [3, 4] (esto es otra fila)")
E = input("Ingrese el escalar")
print(matrizPorEscalar(M1,E))


#SEGUNDA FORMA:

##import numpy as np
##import ast
##
##def matrizPorEscalar(matriz1, escalar):
##    matriz1 = np.matrix(matriz1)
##    
##    return matriz1 * escalar
##
##M1 = ast.literal_eval(input("Ingrese la matriz de la forma [[1,2],[3,4]]: "))
##E = ast.literal_eval(input("Ingrese el escalar"))
##
##
##print('Resultado:', matrizPorEscalar(M1, E))
##
```

El código comentado si funciona (que por cierto ese código es gracias a @FJSevilla) pero al intentar hacer la multiplicación con el código de arriba me devuelve el sgt error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/Calculadoras Metodos/matrices/matrixPorEscalar.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(matrizPorEscalar(M1,E))
  File "I:/Calculadoras Metodos/matrices/matrixPorEscalar.py", line 12, in matrizPorEscalar
    return matriz1 * escalar
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 345, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, other)
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11')
```

Lo que yo entiendo es que son de diferentes tipos los datos que quiero multiplicar pero entonces no sabría como hacer la conversión para que lo pueda hacer, los datos que ingreso son:
1,2;3,4 y el escalar 5 debería retornar 5,15; 15,20

Si alguien conoce alguna solución se lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el error lo estás teniendo en el primer código a causa del tipo de la variable E que es un string!
Proba con una línea que convierta a E en un float. Podés hacerlo dentro de tu función matrizPorEscalar con:
escalar = float(escalar)
O afuera antes de pasarle el argumento a la función:
stringE = input("...")
E = float(stringE)
Saludos!

Comment: Asi es, gracias por notarlo :D